# How to use type maps inside nested objects in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, typemaps

Firstly, a type is created that associates enum keys with types:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B
}

type TypeMap = {
    [MyEnum.A]:string,
    [MyEnum.B]:number
}

interface ObjInterface<T extends keyof TypeMap> {
    obj: T,
    objData: TypeMap[T]
}

interface SecondaryInterface {
    value: string,
    objChosen: ObjInterface<keyof TypeMap>
}
```

Then an object is made where objData's type gets verified against the TypeMap:

```
myObj:SecondaryInterface = {value:"", objChosen:{obj:MyEnum.A, objData:"a string"}}
```

This partly works but when I type objData, it gives a union type hint 'string | number' and not just 'string' because it infers the type from keyof TypeMap rather than the exact TypeMap[T].

Is it possible to get an exact type match for the enum key used and its associated type set in the type map?

It can be made to work using a type assertion but can this be made to work without one?:

```
myObj:SecondaryInterface = {value:"", objChosen:<ObjInterface<MyEnum.A>>{obj:MyEnum.A, objData:"a string"}}
```

Comment: You don't want `ObjInterface<keyof TypeMap>`.  Instead you want to *distribute* `ObjInterface<T>` over unions in `T`. Possibly making it a non-generic *distributive object type* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGbGKm). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your definition, `ObjInterface<MyEnum.A | MyEnum.B>` is a single object type where `obj` can be any `MyEnum` and `objData` can be `string | number`.  But that's no what you want. You'd like `ObjInterface<T>` to *distribute* over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`, so that `ObjInterface<MyEnum.A | MyEnum.B>` is evaluated as `ObjInterface<MyEnum.A> | ObjInterface<MyEnum.B>`. There are different ways to accomplish that, such as using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), but when the thing you want to distribute over is keylike, I usually prefer to write a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  That's where you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

If you have a keylike type `K`, and you want to distribute the type function `F<K>` over unions in `K`, then you can write `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]`.  That turns into a mapped type with one property for each member of `K`, which is immediately indexed into with `K` to make a union of those properties.

For your code that looks like:

```
type ObjInterface<K extends keyof TypeMap> = {
  [P in K]: {
    obj: P,
    objData: TypeMap[P]
  }
}[K]
```

And then `ObjInterface<keyof TypeMap>` evaluates to

```
/* type ObjInterface<keyof TypeMap> = {
    obj: MyEnum.A;
    objData: string;
} | {
    obj: MyEnum.B;
    objData: number;
} */
```

This isn't strictly an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) anymore, so maybe the name should be changed.

---

Of course at this point you haven't actually shown a reason why you need `ObjInterface` to continue to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), if all you care about is plugging in `keyof TypeMap` there. If you don't need that the generic, you can hardcode `K` to be `keyof TypeMap` and make it

```
type ObjInterface = { [K in keyof TypeMap]: {
  obj: K,
  objData: TypeMap[K]
} }[keyof TypeMap]
```

And then the rest of your code is

```
interface SecondaryInterface {
  value: string,
  objChosen: ObjInterface
}

const myObj: SecondaryInterface =
  { value: "", objChosen: { obj: MyEnum.A, objData: "a string" } }; // okay
myObj.objChosen = { obj: MyEnum.B, objData: 123 }; // okay
myObj.objChosen = { obj: MyEnum.A, objData: 123 }; // error
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAggGg1AITQF800AXOAB2CgBVrgYBDKqAXinUwG14lIAOiwBdAFxQAzuQBOASxABzPL37JBBcVGQAjYDJJlKNKAHkdAKwCSIcvoBmzAMa1OKKDwDSUBVADWwHAA9vb0jCxUWtxQQZYSnioxlgAizOTMEgw0EV4iJFDEPAHBoVlMrHloAPQAVFDGtObWtg7Orlz4mLEWEmpCWADcnUkWqekS0vJKQ8RQAD4dmF1xsIjqBENLI2MZ2pB6MjNQNVVkaAp2Mo4uUADKwE5BIAAmzDJwNpfXtNEAbswAGzAwAmsgUynw3QAwgALIKSUASJqfVouQxoR4gaRQCBwJoSe6Y17vFFXNocfDuf5AkFQABEdJwI1h8MRXBGvTW-SZ3R2EjpzCkYKUdIKBQGUCqVRifmYcDQuKagmhcIRIA47O6nIEEA0PJSaV2AEYAEwAZnFkulQVl8sVlmVlhZao17i1qx1wn1o0NElNFuIEqlUH0MiCMiAA)